# Trying to sent data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

In Main

```
override fun pastDada(name: String) {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("USER_NAME", "DDDDDDDD")

        val transction = this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        val profileFragmant = fragment_profile()
        profileFragmant.arguments = bundle
        transction.replace(R.id.container,profileFragmant)
    }
```

In Frafment:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        var view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile2, container, false)


        name = arguments?.getString("USER_NAME")
        Log.e("name", arguments?.getString("USER_NAME").toString())

        Log.e("name", name.toString())
        view.tv_name.text = name

        return view
    }
```

the result of Log.e("name", name.toString()) is always null and I dont know why
maby its becuse my arguments is empty?
and if it is,how am I supose to slove it?

Thanks

Comment: Fragments run inside an activity, so I think you want to pass data from fragment A to fragment B?

Comment: You may need to call `transaction.commit()` ?

Comment: remains the same...

Answer (score 0):

> change your code like this

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    var view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile2, container, false)


    val bundle = arguments
    val name = bundle!!.getString("USER_NAME")

    Log.e("name", name.toString())
    view.tv_name.text = name

    return view
}
```

Comment: I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException if I chane  the code like this